# Access an array outside of a function

Tags: javascript

I have a shopping cart, within the cart I want to store 4 items for each item

```
[0] DB id
[1] description
[2] cost
[3] item id
```

So I have whipped up a 2d array

```
var x=0;
var items= new Array();
var itemNum = 0

Function add(id, desc, cost )
{
items[x]=new Array(4);
items[x][0]=item;
items[x][1]=desc;
items[x][2]=cost;
items[x][3]=itemNum;
x++
itemNum++
}
```

How do access the array outside the function?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How are you trying to access the array?

Comment: You have defined the items array outside te function and are adding items to in within the function, so what you are asking is what you are doing at the moment, don't see the problem?

Comment: You probably want to be using `items.length` and not `x` and `itemNum`. For that matter you probably want to use `items.push()` and not calculate the next item and insert something into it manually.

Comment: Fyi, you can simplyfy the code even more: `items.push([item, desc, cost, itemNum]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var items = [];

function add(id, desc, cost) {
    items.push({ id : id, desc : desc, cost : cost });
}

add(1, 'test', 12345);

alert(items[0].desc);
```

Comment: Thats pretty awesome. How would I find an item in that? For example if I had an id of 12 and

Comment: @maxum Loop through the array, check if `id == idYouAreLookingFor`. Or store your items in an object instead of an array where the item id is the key for direct access.

Answer (score 0):

The array is stored in the variable `items`, so access that as normal.

```
items[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `items` is declared outside of the function, you can access it outside of the function in the normal way:

```
console.log(items[0][0]); //Will print whatever is at 0,0 in the array
```